# How does the EMH get into the "system"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

In the episode "Thaw," a few inhabitants of a planet and Harry Kim are taken hostage by "The Clown," an "evil" entity that is the product of the humans' fears. The Clown won't permit the hostages to leave the system.

Later, the EMH enters. When The Clown asks about him, the EMH states that he is there by "a miracle of technology."

How did the EMH enter the system? The others were put into stasis. The EMH has no brain. Was his program downloaded into one of the stasis pods, then initialized? I'm still not sure how that would allow the EMH to enter the system, since again, he has no brain.

Comment: I'm one answer away from my first tag badge, but not desperate enough to think too hard about *that* episode.

Comment: @fish awww come now it wasn't that bad, at least he isn't asking about threshold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The virtual reality environment in which the clown operated and the hostages were held was populated by characters created from the peoples' bioneural feedback, but it was still just a computer-generated virtual reality environment. I can't imagine the crew would have had any trouble importing the Doctor, and I don't see why he'd need 'a brain' in there any more than he does in the Holodeck or anywhere else.